# How to add Integer to ArrayList<Float>

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to add Integer to an Type safe ArrayList Of Float type.

```
Float a = new Float(1.1);
ArrayList<Float> obj = new ArrayList<Float>();
obj.add(a);//In the obj object I want to add integer. how can I do that?
Integer b = new Integer(1);
obj.add(b);/*The method add(Float) in the type ArrayList<Float> 
                is not applicable for the arguments (Integer)*/
```

Comment: Would it suffice to convert the integer to a float?

Comment: You *can't*. A list of `Float` can only, logically, contain Floats. Luckily both integers and floats are numbers so it's not too hard to convert an integer to a float.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i finally added Integer without changing ArrayList Type, But warnings are generated

```
public class MyArrayList{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Float a = new Float(1.1);
    ArrayList<Float> obj = new ArrayList<Float>();
    obj.add(a);
    function1(obj);
    for (Object obj2 : obj) {
        System.out.println(obj2);
    }
}
private static void function1(ArrayList list) {
    Integer b = new Integer(1);
    list.add(b);
}
```

}

Answer (score 7):

Change the type of ArrayList to: `ArrayList<Number>`.

Because `Number` is the base class of `Float`and `Integer`. So you can store both in the list.

or convert your `Integer` to a `Float` value `obj.add(Float.valueOf(b));`

Comment: Yes, both is possible.  But the `valueOf` forms *“should generally be used in preference to the constructor[s as these methods are] likely to yield significantly better space and time performance by caching frequently requested values.”*  I just think it is better to not give misleading examples to beginners even though it arguably doesn't matter in the context of this question.

Comment: I cannot change the type of ArrayList<Float> to ArrayList<Number>

Comment: @jonesjalapat Than you have to use my second approach. Convert the `Integer` to a `Float`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
obj.add((float) b);
```

This get the `float` number of the `integer`

Or

```
obj.add(Float.parseInt(b));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can not specify the type of the `ArrayList` like :

```
    Float a = new Float(1.1);
    ArrayList<Float> obj = new ArrayList<Float>();
    obj.add(a);//In the obj object i want to add integer how can i do that
    Integer b = new Integer(1);
    ArrayList newobj = (ArrayList) obj;
    newobj.add(b);

    for (Object object : newobj) {
        System.out.println(object.getClass());
    }
```

Would output:

```
class java.lang.Float
class java.lang.Integer
```

Or you can Use an `ArrayList<Number>`:

```
    Float a = new Float(1.1);
    ArrayList<Number> obj = new ArrayList<Number>();
    obj.add(a);//In the obj object i want to add integer how can i do that
    Integer b = new Integer(1);

    obj.add(b);

    for (Number object : obj) {
        System.out.println(object.getClass());
    }
```

Would output:

```
class java.lang.Float
class java.lang.Integer
```

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
obj.add(b.floatValue());
```

Or use an `ArrayList<Number>`.